# Google App Engine NDB Datastore get_by_id to get entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to make the `get_by_id()` work, but I'm not sure what I'm doing is wrong or it does not really work. I'm expecting it to return an entity similar to `ndb.Key('Organization',id).get()`, but both don't work. Here is what I have tried:

```
class CompaniesPage(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    id = self.request.get('id')
    organizations = Organization.query()
    company = Organization.get_by_id(id) # first try
    values = {
      'organizations' : organizations,
      'company' : company,
      'id' : id
    }
    self.render_html('companies.html',values)
```

Second Try:

```
class CompaniesPage(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    id = self.request.get('id')
    organizations = Organization.query()
    company = ndb.Key('Organization',id).get() # second try
    values = {
      'organizations' : organizations,
      'company' : company,
      'id' : id
    }
    self.render_html('companies.html',values)
```

Here is my html using `Jinja2`.

```
 <h3> {{ company }} <small>{{ id }} Category</small></h3>
```

I get the following text:

> None 6201245580656640 Category

I tried to follow the reference about [Model get_by_id](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id) in Google App Engine documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't said how you are creating the entities however based on your example `None 6201245580656640 Category` an id like `6201245580656640` tells me you are probably using an auto generated id, which is an integer not a string.  You are getting the id from a request object and that will be a string.

Convert it to an int in your call `get_by_id(int(id))`

Comment: Yes. This is an auto-generated id. I did not use key name, but id. I also tried `str(id)` but not `int(id)`. I tried it again, and it seems to work fine now.